# How to fix "Cannot Convert from 'bool' Customer.Data.SelectTransactionViewModel"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a class and controller as below

```
//class
public class Payment
 {  
   public Guid ID { get; set; }
   public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
   public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
   public string ConsumerName { get; set; }
 }

 //viewmodel
 public class SelectTransaksiEditorViewModel
 {
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public string ContractNumber { get; set; }
    public string ConsumerName { get; set; }
 }

 public class TransaksiSelectionViewModel
 {
    public List<SelectTransaksiEditorViewModel> Transactions { get; set; }
    public TransaksiSelectionViewModel()
    {
        this.Transactions = new List<SelectTransaksiEditorViewModel>();
    }
 }

 public class DataViewModel
 {
    public TransaksiSelectionViewModel transaksiSelectionViewModel { get; set; }
 }

//controller
public ActionResult Index(int? page,string searchInvoiceNumber)
{
     private DataViewModel dataViewModel = new DataViewModel();
    var model = new TransaksiSelectionViewModel();
    IPagedList<Payment> Payments= null;
    Payments = paymentRepo.GetList_Payments_InTableManualPayment(pageSize, pageNumber);

    foreach (var item in Payments )
    {
       var editorViewModel = new SelectTransaksiEditorViewModel()
       {
          Id = item.ID,
          InvoiceNumber = item.InvoiceNumber,
          ContractNumber = item.ContractNumber,
          ConsumerName = item.ConsumerName,   
       };

       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchInvoiceNumber))
       {
          var data = editorViewModel.InvoiceNumber.Contains(searchInvoiceNumber);
          model.Transactions.Add(data); //error is here
       } else {
          model.Transactions.Add(editorViewModel);
       }                   
    }
    dataViewModel.transaksiSelectionViewModel = model;
    return View(dataViewModel);
}
```

I have listed all the data in the table. and I want to filter all lists based on the invoice number entered. and I get an error when making the invoiceNumber search function. why am I getting this error? please help. thanks:)

> cannot convert from 'bool' to 'CRUDExercise.ViewModel.SelectTransaksiEditorViewModel'

Comment: `string.Contains()` always return `bool` value, you may try to use LINQ on the collection basis: `Payments = paymentRepo.GetList_Payments_InTableManualPayment(pageSize, pageNumber).Where(x => x.InvoiceNumber.Contains(searchInvoiceNumber)).ToList();` after checking `searchInvoiceNumber` variable.

Comment: Try using break points.You if haven't already on the method /line.

Comment: You need to provide contents of `GetList_Payments_InTableManualPayment` method, because the query for `IPagedList<Payment>` stood there. Then modify the method to contain additional parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to this code:

```
var data = editorViewModel.InvoiceNumber.Contains(searchInvoiceNumber);
model.Transactions.Add(data);
```

The first line will evaluate the expression and return the result as `true` or `false` and you are adding the `boolean` result to your model whereas it expects `SelectTransaksiEditorViewModel` hence the error.

As suggested by `@Tetsuya Yamamoto`, you have to fetch the List of payments and put a check on it or you can refactor your code like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? page, string searchInvoiceNumber)
    {
        private DataViewModel dataViewModel = new DataViewModel();
        var model = new TransaksiSelectionViewModel();
        IPagedList<Payment> Payments = null;
        Payments = paymentRepo.GetList_Payments_InTableManualPayment(pageSize, pageNumber);

       var editorViewModelList = new List<SelectTransaksiEditorViewModel>();
       foreach (var item in Payments )
       {
            var editorViewModel = new SelectTransaksiEditorViewModel()
            {
                Id = item.ID,
                InvoiceNumber = item.InvoiceNumber,
                ContractNumber = item.ContractNumber,
                ConsumerName = item.ConsumerName,
            };

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchInvoiceNumber))
            {
              if (editorViewModel.InvoiceNumber.Contains(searchInvoiceNumber))
              {
                   editorViewModelList.Add(editorViewModel);
              }
            }
         }
      model.Transactions.Add(editorViewModelList);
      dataViewModel.transaksiSelectionViewModel = model;
      return View(dataViewModel);
   }
```

Comment: I tried it but it still can't, and the error is
"  SelectTransaksiEditorViewModel does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where' "

Comment: Add this namespace - `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I checked it. But an error in model.Transcations.add(editorViewModelList).

The error is " cannot convert from 'System.collections.generic.list' <CRUDExercise.ViewModel.SelectTransaksiEditorViewModel> to'CRUDExercise.ViewModel.SelectTransaksiEditorViewModel ' "